# How to call parent component page function once child component value updated (ex : change the date picker )

Tags: angular

I have created one filter component as a shared one which is used for filter selection of country its common for all the pages.

when i am changing the country selection need to update the other pages function and UI . please help me how to achieve this in angular 6

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it depending on the sort of relation the `FilterComponent` may have with other pages in your App.

If `FilterComponent` is a direct child of these pages, then you can create an `@Output` property in your `FilterComponent` and then call a function in the pages by binding to it using event binding syntax. I've specified the `@Output` approach in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458061/2622292)** of mine.

If there's no relation between them as such, you can create a SharedService with a private `BehaviorSubject` in exposed as public `Observable` You can follow the approach that I've shared in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992325/2622292)** of mine.

Answer (score 0):

As for your description, I understood that filter component is the child component, And 
  wheneever you filter in the child component the change must come in the parent component.

As per the child and parent communications there are **Event Emitter and View child** 
  properties please look into it.

for reference go through this

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction